# Can I install a 240v heater/air wall unit in my garage with the existing panel and wiring?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

[image]The unit says 230/208v model. It has a 20amp plug on it. 1st question My garage panel was put in 30+ years ago. It is fed from house panel with 12 gauge wire with 2 hots. Is that too weak to add a 240v, 20 amp receptacle?

2nd question: I had a 120v receptacle, for a kiln I no longer have. Can I use this 12 gauge wire and switch receptacle to accommodate the heater plug? I would change breaker to a double 20A.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the panel please?

Comment: Can you post a clear photo of the cables just below the bottom of the box, and also of where the cable with the cloth-wrapped wires enters the box?

Comment: would have to tear down wall to get pic of anything under or behind box.

Comment: Are you saying the box is flush-mounted then?  Because it looks to me to be surface-mounted to a plywood backer from what little I can see in your photo of it

Comment: yes flush on plywood wall

Comment: Can you at least get us a clear photo of where the cable with the cloth-wrapped wires enters the box, then?